# Tag synonym request: [mouse-pointer] -> [mouse-cursor]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[mouse-pointer](/questions/tagged/mouse-pointer) has 10 questions, while [mouse-cursor](/questions/tagged/mouse-cursor) has 49 questions. I suggest making [mouse-pointer](/questions/tagged/mouse-pointer) a synonym for [mouse-cursor](/questions/tagged/mouse-cursor).